# Limit Chef Node attribute search output

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am running the following command to check one of the attribute value on chef :

```
/opt/chefdk/bin/knife node show 10.94.161.38 -a ec2.instance_id -c knife.rb
```

The output is coming out to be :

```
10.94.161.38_151002143810:
  ec2.instance_id: i-1649f4b6
```

Is there a way , it can simply return the value `: i-1649f4b6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply parsed the output with bash:

```
/opt/chefdk/bin/knife node show mynodename -a ec2.instance_id -c knife.rb | tail -1 | cut -d : -f2 |cut -d " " -f2
```